# Content editable is writing on the wrong direction when it has an value

Tags: html, reactjs

So, I have this editable Text that has the attribute of editable, and yes, I'm manipulating the states so I can make it work, but the problem is that the text is not goin' to the right direction when I write rather the opposite, the first character is always at the end.

How should it behave: `stackoverflow...`
How it behaves: `...wolfervokcats`

Here is the component itself:

```
<p
   spellCheck="false"
   ontentEditable="true"
   onInput={props.onInput}
   onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
   onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
   placeholder="New Skill">{props.value}</p>
```

Style:

```
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
display: flex;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
cursor: text;
```

Here is the function that accepts onInput:

```
 function handle(index, e){
 const value = event.target.textContent;
 const newSkills = [...props.skills];
 newSkills[index].skills_group = value;
 props.setSkills(newSkills);
}
```

Comment: I suspect the `onInput` passed from the parent. My guess it's inserting the characters in reverse order, into the state.

Comment: @NiceBooks check the update

Comment: Can you also post the code that sets the `props.value` ? It probably contains a `setValue`.

Comment: @NiceBooks just normal text, if you can upvode

Comment: Please post the parent component code, or at least the `setSkills` function. There is a problem with the state/context update. But I can't help until the code is posted.

Comment: I can confirm the problem occurs because handle function

Comment: Check https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the rendering, i was able to fix with this, keep in mind this will not render the value, and in some cases is not good practice, but works for me:

```js
function handle(index, e){
  const value = event.target.textContent;
  newSkills[index].skills_group = value;
}
```